# Objective-C call a method once a month

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a method that needs to be called the first time the user runs the app (starts or returns the app from background) in a month? 
What is the best way to do this ? (it's an iOs app)... I'm guessing it's in the delegate that this needs to be called

Comment: The easy way is to do it in the application launch process [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
Store the last time the action was performed in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store the last time the method was called and compare that against the current date and call if it's the first time that month (or if there's no stored value, i.e., first time ever). Once the call has been successful, update the saved time.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is to save the date and time when the method is called and then do a check every time on app start up with the current date and saved one to see if they are at least one month apart.  You would then save the current date and run the method again if they are.  You are correct that you would want to do this in the app delegate.  On application did finish launching with options you can do something like this the first time that it launches:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"Last_run_method_date"]) {
    //get new date using [NSDate date] and compare with the date saved in
    //[defaults objectForKey:@"Last_run_method_date"]  If they are more than a month apart
    //[self methodToRun];
} else {
    [defaults setBbject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"Last_run_method_date"];
}
```

In the method that is run once a month you would want to refresh the date when it runs by doing this inside of the method:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBbject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"Last_run_method_date"];
```

Sorry if the code is not 100% correct, i am typing on a pc.

Answer (score 0):

I would schedule a localnotification for that! its like cron for ios :D

use `UILocalNotification`